# Writing a fixed field as a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

I have $G = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(w) : \mathbb{Q})$ where $w = e^{2\pi i/p}$ for $p$ prime.

I have that there exists a (unique) element in $G$ of order 2, say $\phi$.

I'm trying to express the fixed field of the cyclic subgroup $<\phi>$ of $G$ as a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. That is, trying to find a $\beta \in <\phi>^{\dagger}$ such that $<\phi>^{\dagger} = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

I can see $\phi$ fixes $\alpha = w + w^{-1}$, as $\phi(w) = w^{-1}$:
For every conjugate $w^i$ of $w$ in $\mathbb{Q}(w)$ (they all are), there exists a unique automorphism $\bar{\phi}$ sending $w$ to $w^i$. If $\bar{\phi}(w) = w^{-1}$, then $\bar{\phi}^2(w)=(w^{-1})^{-1} = w$, so $\bar{\phi}$ has order 2, hence $\bar{\phi}=\phi$ and $\phi(w) = w^{-1}$.

I was going to try to show $<\phi>^{\dagger}=\mathbb{Q}(w + w^{-1})$ but got as far as showing $\mathbb{Q}(w+w^{-1}) \subseteq<\phi>^{\dagger}$ (as $w+w^{-1} $ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is in $<\phi>^{\dagger}$).

---

I tried the case for p=5, and managed to show the required reverse containment:

Let $x \in <\phi>^{\dagger} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(w)$.

So $x = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1w + ... + \lambda_{4}w^4$, for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{Q}$

$\phi$ fixes $x$: $\phi(\lambda_0 + \lambda_1w + \lambda_2w^2 + \lambda_3w^3 + \lambda_{4}w^4)=\lambda_0 + \lambda_1w^4 + \lambda_2w^3 + \lambda_3w^2 + \lambda_{4}w$ (as $\phi(w) = w^4$, $\phi(w^2) = w^3$, etc).

Thus $\lambda_1 = \lambda_4$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$.

So $x = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1(w+w^4) + \lambda_2(w^2 + w^3)$.

Luckily, $(w + w^4)^2 = w^2 + 1 + w^3$, so we have $x = (\lambda_0 - \lambda_2) + \lambda_1(w+w^4) + \lambda_2(w + w^4)^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(w+w^4)$,

which (phew...) establishes the reverse containment for p=5.

---

It's a bit fiddly though; is it possible to generalise this for general p? In particular, it seems necessary to know a pattern for where $\phi$ sends each of the conjugates of $w$, and also a generalisation of a trick for rewriting $w^2 + w^3$ in terms of $w + w^4$.

I'd appreciate any comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general trick is to show that $[\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p) : \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})] = 2 = | \langle \phi \rangle|$ by explicitly writing down an irreducible quadratic polynomial in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})[x]$ that has $\zeta_p$ as a root, namely 
$$
(x - \zeta_p)(x - \zeta_p^{-1}) = x^2 - (\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})x + 1
$$

Since $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$ is fixed by $\phi$, the Galois correspondence gives you that it must be the fixed field.

Comment: Ah, I see: Since $|<\phi>| = 2 = |\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) : <\phi>^{\dagger}| = |\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})|$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}) \subseteq <\phi>^{\dagger}$, this forces them to be equal. Thanks!

Comment: ...I can't think of a way of showing that quadratic is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$, or why $\zeta_p \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$

Comment: Figured it out with help from: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384763/show-zeta-p-notin-mathbbq-zeta-p-zeta-p-1/384776 ]. Needed to notice that $\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1} = \zeta_p + \bar{\zeta_p} \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \bar{\zeta_p})$ is a real subspace, so can't contain a non-real $\zeta_p$.