# Show $\zeta_p \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I asked a question here: [[Writing a fixed field as a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384703/writing-a-fixed-field-as-a-simple-extension-of-mathbbq) ], but realised I couldn't justify why the given quadratic was irreducible.

Thus: Is there a way of showing $\zeta_p \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$ (where p is prime)?

I think $|\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}) : \mathbb{Q}|=\frac{p-1}{2}$, so trying to derive some contradiction from $\zeta_p$ being a linear combination of $\{(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})^i\}_{i=1\to p-1/2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, what happens is that $\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1} = \zeta_p + \bar{\zeta_p} = 2\cos{\left(\frac{2\pi}{p} \right)} \in \mathbb{R}$ so $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Therefore it can't contain any nonreal complex numbers.

Comment: Oh gosh, of course, the sum of a number and its conjugate is always real, so $\zeta_p + \bar{\zeta_p} \in \mathbb{R}$. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @maliky0_o Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 6):

Adrián Barquero hit the nail on the head, but if you were curious and wanted a bit more information, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1})$ is in fact the maximal real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})$, as it is the subfield fixed by the subgroup generated by $\tau|_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})}$, or complex conjugation restricted to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})$. Since $\zeta_{p}$ is not fixed under complex conjugation, it cannot be in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1})$.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. I was actually originally trying to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}) = <\phi>^{\dagger}$, the fixed field of an automorphism $\phi$ of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p):\mathbb{Q})$, where $\phi(\zeta_p) = \zeta_p^{-1} = \bar{\zeta_p}$, so was the complex conjugation map. Of course since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, if $\zeta_p \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1})$, then  they would be equal. But we can distinguish them as $\phi$ fixes $\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}$ but not $\zeta_p$, which is a contradiction...